# How can i take value from input select type and use it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have this project where I have to make a clothing store and I want to do the following:

I have this code in html:

```
<select class="sizeb" style="display: none;">
     <option value="xxs">XXS</option>
     <option value="xs">XS</option>
     <option value="s">S</option>
     <option value="m">M</option>
     <option value="l">L</option>
     <option value="xl">XL</option>
     <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
</select>
```

and with JavaScript I want to take the option value, check it's value and create a `var price;` then check and set a price:

```
var x = <somehow to get the value>;
if (x == 'xxs')
    price = 5;
else if(x == 'xs') 
    price = 10;
```

and display it later this way:

```
document.getElementById("PriceTag").innerHTML = "Pret: " + price + " RON";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('sizeb').value

Comment: @Cruiser this is just  gonna work went the page load, but not when he change the element.

Comment: Why is the select (dropdown) hidden? display:none. How would user select a different size?

Comment: @NawedKhan it is hidden because i have two dropdowns one for kids witch size is shown by age and one for adults witch size is shown by actual size(L, XL ,M etc) and a function handles that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you just get a reference to the HTML element and assign that to a variable:

```
var select = document.querySelector(".sizeb");
```

Then you get the value:

```
var val = select.value;
```

Then you do your logic and calculations:

```
var x = <somehow to get the value>;
if (x == 'xxs'){
    price = 5;
} else if(x == 'xs') {
    price = 10;
}
```

And, then display the result:

```
document.getElementById("PriceTag").innerHTML = "Pret: " + price + " RON";
```

**NOTE: You have your select to be hidden initially. If that's the case, no one will ever be able to select a value from it.**

Now, you also have to decide "when" you want all this to be done. That could be when the value in the select changes. BUt, if that's the case, you should add a first `option` of something like `--- Select One ---`, because if the user wants the first selection, they won't do anything, which won't trigger the `change` event. So, putting it all together, we get:

```js
// Get a reference to the select
var select = document.querySelector(".sizeb");

// Set up an event handler that runs when the value in the select changes:
select.addEventListener("change", function(){

    // Then you get the value:
    var x = select.value;  
  
    var price = null;
  
    // Then you do your logic and calculations. 
    // And if will work, but for this a switch is better
    switch (x) {
      case 'xxs' :
        price = 5;
        break;
      case 'xs' :
        price = 10;
        break;
      case 's' :
        price = 15;
        break;
      case 'm' :
        price = 20;
        break;
      case 'l' :
        price = 25;
        break;
      case 'xl' :
        price = 30;
        break;
      case 'xxl' :
        price = 35;
        break;
    }


    document.getElementById("PriceTag").innerHTML = "Pret: " + price + " RON";  
});
```

```html
<select class="sizeb">
     <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
     <option value="xxs">XXS</option>
     <option value="xs">XS</option>
     <option value="s">S</option>
     <option value="m">M</option>
     <option value="l">L</option>
     <option value="xl">XL</option>
     <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
</select>

<div id="PriceTag"></div>
```

Comment: it is hidden because i have two dropdowns one for kids witch size is shown by age and one for adults witch size is shown by actual size(L, XL ,M etc) and a function handles that

Comment: Also how do i put this code in an external Java Script file?

Comment: You just literally copy all the JavaScript into a text file and save it with a `.js` extension. Then, just before the`body` section of your HTML file closes ( `</body>`), you reference it like this: `<script src='relative path to file'></script>`. Make sure the text file is saved with `utf-8` encoding applied to it.

Comment: As i said i have two lists (shown each when needed) to set this up for both i just copy paste it or can i do it 'better' than copy pasting?

Comment: You take all of the JavaScript and "cut" it from the `.html` file and paste it into the new `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can:
1-Add an listener to the select like this

```
<select onchange="someFunction(this)" class="sizeb" style="display: none;>
```

2-create a function like this:

```
function someFunction(element){
    va price = element.value;
    document.getElementById("PriceTag").innerHTML = "Pret: " + price + " RON";
}
```

Comment: Please don't advise people to use inline HTML event attributes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus He has his html in this way, so i'm just trying to help with the code he has. But thank you, i'll don't no more.